# If command isn't found reply with message

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make my bot check every message, if one is a command, check if the command is right, if it isn't, reply with "Invalid comand, type z!help for a list of commands".

What I have:

```
fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  files.forEach(file => {
    if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
    let props = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    let commandName = file.split(".")[0];
    console.log(`Attempting to load command ${commandName}`);
    client.commands.set(commandName, props);
  });
});

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("z!")){
    if (message.content !== commandName){
      message.reply("Invalid command")
    }
  }
})
```

But I get

```
ReferenceError: commandName is not defined
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide more info like at what line does the error appear and where is this commandName firstly defined?

```js
fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    files.forEach(file => {
      if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
      let props = require(`./commands/${file}`);
      let commandName = file.split(".")[0];
      console.log(`Attempting to load command ${commandName}`);
      client.commands.set(commandName, props);
    });
  });
  
  client.on('message', (message, files) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("z!")){
        files.forEach(file => {
            if (message.content !== file.split(".")[0]){
                message.reply("Invalid command")
            }
        });
    }
  })
```

Probably the code here won't work, so, here's another idea:

```js
let globalFile;

function passFile(file) { // Generally speaking, that's a bad idea.
    globalFile = file
    return file
}

fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    files.forEach(file => {
      if (!file.endsWith(".js")) return;
      let props = require(`./commands/${file}`);
      let commandName = passFile(file.split(".")[0]);
      console.log(`Attempting to load command ${commandName}`);
      client.commands.set(commandName, props);
    });
  });
  
  client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("z!")){
        files.forEach(file => {
            if (message.content !== globalFile){ // Check if globalFile is something
                message.reply("Invalid command")
            }
        });
    }
  })
```

Comment: commandName is defined above in the code provided, for the line, it's 14 if I reckon correctly.

Comment: Oh sorry, I haven't seen it! Anyway, I can clearly see that commandName isn't declared outside of the function fs.readdir so, client.on won't be able to access it. You have to return it somehow in order to be accessible outside of the function.

Comment: I see, do you think there is an easier way to do this?

Comment: You could pass files at clients.on too so you can recreate it. Let me edit my answer with the code.

Comment: Check out the answer again, just updated it.

Comment: Anyway, note that you should modify the function client.on in order to take the files parameter. I don't know much about discord.js so i'm just bruteforcing it.

Comment: All good, I'll try out some methods out on my own. Thanks for helping